# How echo a datetime in "YYYY-MM-DD" format in linux and powershell with a same command?

Tags: linux, powershell, command-line-interface

I do have a php 'composer' command which generates a .zip package for deploy.

this package should have the datetime as sufix, for instance `release-2018-09-12` or `release-2018091`.

However some of our programmers and freelancers use both windows and Linux.

The `date +%Y-%m-%d` only works on Linux. but not on windows.

How can I write a command that works both in Linux or windows (powershell)? or a workaround to it?

Comment: `date -u +%Y-%m-%d` would work in PowerShell, not sure if `-u` is an existing switch in `date` on linux

Comment: In Powershell: `(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: What do you mean by "not on Windows"? What do you see there instead?

Comment: > date +%Y-%m-%d
System cannot accept the typed date.
@JoelCoehoorn

Comment: So users are typing in a date value? Or, if you're parsing this later, it seems like that's the problem, rather than the output here, and that's what you need to work on.

Answer (score -1):

The '-UFormat' switch of Get-Date stands for 'Unix format'

```
Get-Date -Uformat "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Comment: it's not meant to, it's just the %Y, %m %d